# How to turn SQL script into a function?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have an SQL script (written in SQL Developer) that I'm using to create some state-specific data. I have to run this script for every state in the US. Right now there are several places in my script where I have a clause restricting the output to a given state (e.g., "where [table.column] = 'AK' "). So, if I want to run the script for different states, I have to manually replace every instance of the given state code (e.g., from 'AK' to 'AL').

Is there a way to turn my SQL script into a function, with the state code as the function's single parameter? It would be really nice if I could just type in "function([state code])" instead of the scrolling through the whole script and tweaking it 50 times!

Comment: Pls send us your sql. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't because it may have CBI in it. However, I think I might have the answer. SQL Developer allows you to write procedures, correct? If I can figure out how to write a procedure then I think I'll have solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

Create sample table/data:

```
create table us_census
(state varchar2(10),
county_population number,
county varchar2(10)
);

insert into us_census VALUES ('AK',100,'county1');
insert into us_census VALUES ('AK',150,'county2');
insert into us_census VALUES ('AL',200,'county3');
insert into us_census VALUES ('AL',100,'county4');
```

Sample function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_population_per_state(p_state IN varchar2) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS population NUMBER;
   BEGIN 
      SELECT sum(county_population) 
      INTO population 
      FROM us_census
      WHERE state = p_state  --for example: 'AK'
      GROUP BY state;   
      RETURN(population); 
    END;
/
```

sample execution:

```
declare v_population number;
BEGIN
for r in (select distinct state from us_census)
loop
   select get_population_per_state(r.state) into v_population from dual;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('State: ' || r.state || ' Population :' ||v_population);
end loop;
END;
```

Sample Result:

```
State: AK Population :250 
State: AL Population :300
```